# How to implement shortcuts/hotkeys in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

We're trying to add keyboard shortcuts to our app. I thought the FocusableActionDetector widget may be a good choice so I've tried wrapping our app with it however it prevents autofocus from working in form fields. From reading the docs it seems like FocusableActionDetector is more suited for a single component than the entire app.

This post has been helpful in understanding the FocusableActionDetector widget:
https://medium.com/flutter/handling-web-gestures-in-flutter-e16946a04745

You can see our disabled implementation here: https://github.com/invoiceninja/flutter-client/blob/develop/lib/ui/app/app_shortcuts.dart#L80

Thanks for your help!